# how to populate an array of MyObjects PHP

Tags: php, arrays, web-services

Hi I'm new to PHP I would like to know hoy to populate the tweets array in order to return it.

```
<?php

class TwitterService {
private $params = null;
private $tweets = array(

);

public function getParams() {
    return $this->params;
}

public function setParams($params) {
    $this->params = $params;
}


public function __construct($params) {
    $this->setParams($params);
}
public function getTweets(){
    private $tweet1 = new Tweet(
            id = 253338336415064064,
            created_at = 'Wed, 03 Oct 2012 03:39:00 +0000',
            profile_image_url = 'http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1529778154\/Facebook_normal.jpg',
            text = 'Lo real es lo real by @AnaliaRob tratando de expresarse vaya 1 a saber sobre q! Es un proverbio milenario. Only xa genios'
        );
    private $tweet2 = new Tweet(
            id: 253324444091703298,
            created_at: 'Wed, 03 Oct 2012 02:43:48 +0000',
            profile_image_url: 'http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1529778154\/Facebook_normal.jpg',
            text: 'Lo real es lo real by @AnaliaRob, trantando de expresarse vaya uno a saber sobre que!'
        );  

    return $tweets;
}

class Tweet{
    private $id = null;
    private $created_at = null;
    private $profile_image_url = null;
    private $text= null;
};
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tweets = array( $tweet1, $tweet2 );
return $tweets;
```

**EDIT :**

To explain, you can't populate the array(`$tweets`) in the declaration zone because `$tweet1` and `$tweet2` doesn't exist yet, you declare/assign them in the function `getTweets()`.

If you don't need to access `$tweets` elsewhere in your code you can skip the `$tweets` declaration and `return array( $tweet1, $tweet2 );` in `getTweets()` as shown by @MarvinLabs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tweets[] = $myTweet;
```

or

```
$tweets = array( $tweet1, $tweet2 );
```

---

Edit:

```
public function getTweets(){
    private $tweet1 = new Tweet(
            id = 253338336415064064,
            created_at = 'Wed, 03 Oct 2012 03:39:00 +0000',
            profile_image_url = 'http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1529778154\/Facebook_normal.jpg',
            text = 'Lo real es lo real by @AnaliaRob tratando de expresarse vaya 1 a saber sobre q! Es un proverbio milenario. Only xa genios'
        );
    private $tweet2 = new Tweet(
            id: 253324444091703298,
            created_at: 'Wed, 03 Oct 2012 02:43:48 +0000',
            profile_image_url: 'http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1529778154\/Facebook_normal.jpg',
            text: 'Lo real es lo real by @AnaliaRob, trantando de expresarse vaya uno a saber sobre que!'
        );  
    // Option 1
    return array( $tweet1, $tweet2 );

    // Option 2
    $result = array();
    $result[] = $tweet1;
    $result[] = $tweet2;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Where should I populate it, in the declaration or in the method return? Thank you ery much!

Answer (score 0):

You can access them this way, inside the function `getTweets`:

```
  $tweets = array( $tweet1, $tweet2,...);
```